# How to set the resolution parameter for Louvain modularity in igraph?

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, sna

is there a way to set the resolution parameter when using the function *cluster_louvain* to detect communities in *igraph* for R? It makes a lot of difference for the result, as this parameter is related to the hierarchical dissimilarity between nodes. Thank you.

Comment: In the current version they added the resolution parameter in the cluster_louvain() function

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a loot at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is through the `resolution` package, available in this link https://github.com/analyxcompany/resolution

It is based on this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1770.pdf

It pretty much has 2 functions `cluster_resolution()` and `cluster_resolution_RandomOrderFULL()`.
In both you can state the resolution `t` and how many repetitions you want `rep`. And, you can just use the igraph object in the function.

```
cluster_resolution_RandomOrderFULL(g,t=0.5)
cluster_resolution_RandomOrderFULL(g,rep=20)
```

NOTE/EDIT: it will not accept signed networks though! I'm trying to either contact the owner of the code or costumize it myself to make it suitable for signed networks.

EDIT2: I was able to translate the function community_louvain.m from the [Brain Connectivity Toolbox](https://sites.google.com/site/bctnet/Home/functions) for Matlab to R.

Here is the [github link](https://github.com/coelhocao/Brain_Network_analysis/blob/master/signed_louvain.R) for the `signed_louvain()`

you can pretty much just put for ex. `signed_louvain(g, gamma = 1, mod = 'modularity')`
it works with igraph or matrix objects as input. If it has negative values, you have to choose `mod = 'neg_sym'` or `'neg_asym'`.